# how to retrieve the below data with specific key (i need host and ip values) int the spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My data frame is given below  i want to retrieve individual keys and values

```
       header

[host, TUSTX002LK]
[ip, 92.168.1.118]
[vzid, V740723]
[version, 16.3.16.0]
```

expected output 
host          ip              vzid       version
TUSTX002LK    92.168.1.118    V740723    16.3.16.0

Answer (score 0):

First you should construct a map

```
val data = scala.collection.mutable.Map(
  "host" -> "TUSTX002LK"
  "ip" -> "92.168.1.118"
  "vzid" -> "V740723"
  "version" -> "16.3.16.0"
)
```

Then you can access the values through the keys

Comment: Thank you for sharing the info it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

As you already have a dataframe you can register it as a table or create a tempview and then use select to retrieve value for any key.

eg : 
df.createOrReplaceTempView("header")

sqlContext.sql("select val from header where key = 'ip'");

Comment: Thank you for sharing the info it would be helpful

Comment: How are you reading this data. It will be helpful in giving you a clear solution. Are you are reading from a text file?